# html2canvas not converting html having with gradient style

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

[image: bars with gradient color not getting converted]I am using "html2canvas" +  to change html chart to image. when bars are having black color style its gets converted fine. but when html bars having gradient CSS it does not converted. Attaching screenshots here.

```
        html2canvas(elementDom, {[enter image description here][1]
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            getCanvas = canvas;
            var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var newData = imgageData.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
            });
```

[image: bars with black color gets converted]

Comment: No html2canvas doesn't support all CSS rules. [It's written on the project's homepage](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/#browser-compatibility). But are these CSS gradients btw or external svg ? Anyway, you should use [the latest version](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases).

Comment: @Kaiido they are CSS gradients and not svg. and I have a latest version of html2canvas.

Comment: Then you will have to write all the different css gradients versions to canvas yourself and then post a pull request to the project, because nobody had enough time in last few years yet to do it. Also, if you were using latest version, your code would throw an error... latest version returns a promise